# Applescript record can not be coerced to application's predefined record type

Tags: applescript

For example, I am trying using BetterZip for extracting files in applescript automation

The dictionary shows the syntax of the `unarchive` command:

COMMAND SYNTAX
`unarchive file or list of file ¬
     with preset text ¬
     with options unarchive options`

where the `unarchive options` is a predefined record type with a set of properties:

`unarchive options (record)
PROPERTIES
Property            Access   Type
---------------------------------
clean archive       get/set  boolean
create extra folder get/set  create extra folder (enum)
destination         get/set  file or destination folder
password            get/set  text
trash archive       get/set  boolean`

In my code I want to use extract files with BetterZip

```
tell application "BetterZip"
    unarchive "/path/to/zipfile" with options {clean archive:false, destination:original, create extra folder:never, trash archive:false}
end tell
```

In **Script Debugger 6**, the error is `unable to coerce the data to the desired type {errAECoerionFail:-1700}`
The status bar shows `Stopped {Error: Can't make {clean archive:false, destination:original, create extra folder:never, trash archive:false} type unarchive options`

So how to pass a record of a `unarchive options` type to the command?

**Update:**

I have found out the root of the problem, but I still can not figure out the solution.

The `unarchive options` can be retrieved via BetterZip's command `get extraction preset with name "preset name"`, the return value is a `record` for example one in Script Debugger showing in AEPrint format as `{ 'uoDs':'Orig', 'uoEF':'efNv' }`.

If I create a record with same keys and values, the AEPrint is `{ 'aoDs':'Orig', 'uoEF':'efNv' }`, noticing the internal token for `destination` is different. (one is `uoDs`, the other is `aoDs`).

Further more, if I combine the records: `{destination:original} & (get extraction preset with name "ExtractHere")`, the return value appears to have duplicate keys rather than merging them: `{destination:original, destination:original, create extra folder:never}` and the AEPrint is `{ 'aoDs':'Orig', 'uoDs':'Orig', 'uoEF':'efNv' }`.

So I think this is the reason why the unarchive command won't accept an `unarchive options`-like parameter because of the mismatched underneath key name.

But how to create one that matches the correct type?

Comment: Two possibilities: 1. try adding a `class:unarchive options` property to the record; 2. try adding a `password:""` property to the record. (When you figure out which, you might want to email the developer asking them to improve their dictionary documentation.) You may also need to pass a file object (`POSIX file "/path/to/zipfile"`) rather than a path string as the direct parameter. Don't forget you can also use `do shell script` to unzip files via the command line `gzip`/`unzip` tools; no app needed.

Comment: @foo, 1: Doesn't work. 2 Doesn't work. 3. the command is working without the `with options`, using `text` or `POSIX file` is irrelevant. 4. the question is not really about programming BetterZip, it's about coercing record types, because I've experienced the same issue from another application in the same scenario.(though the reason I prefer BetterZip is its auto handling various archive types, progress indicator and auto create sub-folder. I know it all can be done via shell script, and I have done that in a Linux environment, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel on mac)

Comment: Is the record's `destination` property correct? Your dictionary extract is kind of fuzzy on its expected type (`file or destination folder`). TBH, the command's design looks kinda janky; if you still can't get it to work I recommend contacting the vendor for assistance and file a bug report [if it's broken]/feature request [for better documentation] while you're at it.

Comment: @foo, I update the question

Comment: Well done, excellent bit of sleuthing. Yes, the `destination` keyword should _only_ have one four-char code associated with it, not two. File a bug report with the developer, as their dictionary is clearly broken. Here's a hacky workaround for the screwed-up terminology while you're waiting: `(run script "{«class uoDs»:«class Orig»}")`. That'll always return a dictionary that contains the right codes, to which you can then concatenate the other properties as needed.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to unzip a file in AppleScript, I just use "do shell script" with the "unzip" command eg.

```
do shell script "/usr/bin/unzip \"/path/to/zipfile\" -d \"/path/to/output/location\""
```